# How to sort by string column with letters first?

Tags: python, postgresql, sorting, sqlalchemy

Say, I want to sort records by name and name may start from numeric letter too.

If I do just

```
Something.query.order_by(Something.name)
```

I have the following order:

- 1st in a row
- 33 teeth
- Beta version
- Zesty

How to change the query to put numbers after letters:

- Beta version
- Zesty
- 1st in a row
- 33 teeth

Answer (score 2):

Adding an initial sort clause to segment leading-numeric from leading-non-numeric seems to be working:

```python
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_url)
metadata = sa.MetaData()

mytable = sa.Table('mytable', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

# 1. default sort
stmt = sa.sql.select([mytable.c.thing])\
    .select_from(mytable)\
    .order_by(mytable.c.thing)
with engine.begin() as conn:
    print(conn.execute(stmt).fetchall())
    # [('1st in a row',), ('99 beers',), ('Beta version',), ('Zesty',)]

# 2. non-numeric first
sort_boundary = '9' * mytable.c.thing.type.length
print(sort_boundary)
# 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
#
stmt = sa.sql.select([mytable.c.thing])\
    .select_from(mytable)\
    .order_by(mytable.c.thing <= sort_boundary, mytable.c.thing)
with engine.begin() as conn:
    print(conn.execute(stmt).fetchall())
    # [('Beta version',), ('Zesty',), ('1st in a row',), ('99 beers',)]
```